# SQL Server 2005 windows group permissions overriding individual server logins

Tags: security, sql-server-2005, permissions

---

Hi,

I was wondering if someone knows a way round this. I have a database which needs to be accessed by a Windows Group with read only access. Some individuals in this group need write access.

I have added the group and then the individual logins and setup the permissions accordingly but the Windows Group seems to take precedence over the individual logins.

Does anyone know how to get around this?

Thanks

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permissions are cumulative, with the exception that DENY rights will overwrite GRANTs.

If you grant select to the group and deny update to the group, then grant update to the login they will not be able to update.

Make sure that you haven't denied any rights to the group or to public.

Comment: Thank you

I removed the deny from the specific columns and this is now working.

Comment: No problem, glad it was that easy.